# Button remains selected and .classList toggle in JS runs only every other time

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, cross-browser

I am trying to polish up an exercise from a course i am taking in Frontend Development. The project is a random color gradient background generator.

I am using DOM manipulation to set colors, animate buttons through CSS classes, etc.

I have doubts on how to fix 3 things though:

**1-** My "Randomize" button stays selected once pressed and a visible blue selection box is around it. So it won't play the hover animation until the user clicks out of the button.

**2-** The styles for my HTML color input elements do not work in Firefox as well as the CSS animation. I am not very familiar with fixing compatibility, so can't figure this one out :/

**3-** To animate the two color inputs, i am using the classList.toggle javascript method to toggle an animated CSS class. Naturally, as the method name suggests, it **toggles** the class, meaning the animation only plays every other time the user clicks the randomize button. I have tried many combinations of "re-toggling" the class, to no avail.

I would really appreciate any input on these questions, as it helps me immensely in the learning process!

Thank you very much for reading thus far and thank you in advance for any help!

The code is as follows (and pardon me it is still not very pretty or refactored :P):

```js
// variables
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var rndmBtn = document.getElementById("randomizerButton");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");

//  generate a random color
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
  };

// set the initial gradient on page load
function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1.value + ", " + color2.value + ")";
    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
};

// picks two random colors, assigns them to variables and sets input value and BG as the new colors
function randomColors() {
    var rndmCol1 = getRandomColor();
    var rndmCol2 = getRandomColor();

    document.querySelector(".color1").setAttribute("value", rndmCol1);
    document.querySelector(".color2").setAttribute("value", rndmCol2);
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + rndmCol1 + ", " + rndmCol2 + ")";
    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
};

// function for pressing the space bar
function pressSpace() {
    if  (event.keyCode === 32) {
        randomColors();
        animateButton();
    }
    };

// function for animated button

function animateButton() {
    color1.classList.toggle("animated");
    color2.classList.toggle("animated");  
};

function animateButton2() {
    color1.classList.toggle("animated");
    color2.classList.toggle("animated");  
};

// call function that sets initial gradient on page load
setGradient();

//  event listeners for color picking
window.addEventListener("load", randomColors);
rndmBtn.addEventListener("click", animateButton);
color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
rndmBtn.addEventListener("click", randomColors);
window.addEventListener("keydown", pressSpace);
```

```css
body {
    font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    top: 15%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #73ff01, #0bebeb);
}

h1 {
    font: 600 3.5em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    width: 100%;
}

h3 {
    font: 900 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#randomizerButton {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border: 1.5px solid;
    border-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0.01);;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#randomizerButton:hover {
    background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0.2);;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#randomizerButton:active {
    background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0.4);;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

input[type=color]{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 10px;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
 padding: 0;
}

input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.color1, .color2 {
    border: none;
}

.colorInfo {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1.5px solid;
    border-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Input boxes Animation */

.animated {
    -webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
    animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
  }
  
/* Generated with Bounce.js */
  
  @-webkit-keyframes animation { 
    0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    3.6% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.705, 0.717, 0, 0, -0.551, 0.841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.705, 0.717, 0, 0, -0.551, 0.841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    4.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.606, 0.804, 0, 0, -0.641, 0.776, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.606, 0.804, 0, 0, -0.641, 0.776, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    7.21% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.208, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.897, 0.463, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.208, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.897, 0.463, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    8.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.06, 1.007, 0, 0, -0.957, 0.319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.06, 1.007, 0, 0, -0.957, 0.319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    12.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.179, 0.989, 0, 0, -1.005, 0.015, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.179, 0.989, 0, 0, -1.005, 0.015, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    13.51% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.191, 0.986, 0, 0, -1.004, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.191, 0.986, 0, 0, -1.004, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    17.22% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.198, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.198, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    19.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.163, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.995, -0.103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.163, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.995, -0.103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    26.03% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.053, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.998, -0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.053, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.998, -0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    28.33% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.024, 1, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.041, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.024, 1, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.041, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    32.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.007, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.007, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    39.44% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.017, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.017, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    44.74% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.009, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.009, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    57.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    61.66% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    82.28% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    83.98% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
  }
  
  @keyframes animation { 
    0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    3.6% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.705, 0.717, 0, 0, -0.551, 0.841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.705, 0.717, 0, 0, -0.551, 0.841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    4.3% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.606, 0.804, 0, 0, -0.641, 0.776, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.606, 0.804, 0, 0, -0.641, 0.776, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    7.21% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.208, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.897, 0.463, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.208, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.897, 0.463, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    8.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.06, 1.007, 0, 0, -0.957, 0.319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.06, 1.007, 0, 0, -0.957, 0.319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    12.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.179, 0.989, 0, 0, -1.005, 0.015, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.179, 0.989, 0, 0, -1.005, 0.015, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    13.51% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.191, 0.986, 0, 0, -1.004, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.191, 0.986, 0, 0, -1.004, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    17.22% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.198, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.198, 0.982, 0, 0, -0.997, -0.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    19.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.163, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.995, -0.103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.163, 0.987, 0, 0, -0.995, -0.103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    26.03% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.053, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.998, -0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.053, 0.999, 0, 0, -0.998, -0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    28.33% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.024, 1, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.041, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.024, 1, 0, 0, -0.999, -0.041, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    32.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.007, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.007, 1, 0, 0, -1, -0.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    39.44% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.017, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.017, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    44.74% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.009, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0.009, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    57.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    61.66% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(-0.001, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    82.28% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    83.98% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
  }

 /* Bounce In */

.hvr-bounce-in {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-in:hover, .hvr-bounce-in:focus, .hvr-bounce-in:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 2.02, 0.31, -0.36);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 2.02, 0.31, -0.36);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Gradient Background</title>
</head>
<body id="gradient">
    <h1>Background Generator</h1>
    <input class="color1 animated" type="color" name="color1" id="" value="#73ff01">
    <input class="color2 animated" type="color" name="color2" id="" value="#0bebeb">
    <button id="randomizerButton" class="hvr-bounce-in">Randomize!</button>
    <div class="colorInfo">
        <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
        <h3></h3>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 3) https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is great link. Makes a lot of sense, but it didn't work for my button animation unfortunately :(  don't know what to try anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I could help you with the button question. The button is still active after you click it and would require you to click it again before it gets deactivated => This is what I understand from your question.

to fix that, write a simple function that toggles the button on every click, so you won't need to click it again to deactivate it.

```
function toggleBtn () { this.rndmBtn = !this.rndmBtn};
```

This should work. Then call toggleBtn() wherever the button needs to be clicked.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Benedict. Thank you very much for the input! However, it didn't work, unfortunately :( I created the function and called it with `rndmBtn.addEventListener("mouseup", toggleBtn);` and it didn't work. i also tried some other ways, but no cigar there as well..let me know if you have any other ideas or if i did something wrong! Thanks again!!

Comment: So I'm going to run a little demo on codepen soon just to test this. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hello Paulo, go through this [link](https://codepen.io/benneee/pen/MLBQmG?editors=1111) and tell me what you think

Comment: That's a good implementation. My problem is though that i am using a `classList.toggle` to add an animation class to another element. In that case, it doesn't work, unfortunately. I found a solution which is to use 
`function toggleBtn () {
    var rndmBtn = document.getElementById('randomizerButton');
    this.blur();
  }
  
  rndmBtn.addEventListener('mouseup', toggleBtn);`

Thank you very much for the effort and helpfulness! Really appreciate it.